# Jupyter notebook cannot connect to kernel when "code.py" found in same directory

Tags: python, jupyter

As the title says, when I have a file called "code.py" in the directory in which I try to launch jupyter notebook, the terminal gives me a series of error messages related to not being able to execute some lines of code in that file. Meanwhile, I get the error message of not being able to connect to the ipykernel in the browser interface. If I rename the file from "code.py" to something else like "test.py", it works.

I have not found any documentation on this but can someone point me such conventions that are not permitted?

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter notebook and jypyter lab both work when a file named "code.py" is present in the directory. Maybe you could provide a small reproducible example of the code.py that causes the issue?

```
user@laptop:/tmp$ mkdir /tmp/so
user@laptop:/tmp$ cd /tmp/so
user@laptop:/tmp/so$ echo “print(1+1)” > code.py
user@laptop:/tmp/so$ cat code.py
print(1+1)
user@laptop:/tmp/so$ jupyter notebook
2
[I 23:03:33.711 NotebookApp] [jupyter_nbextensions_configurator] enabled 0.4.1
[I 2022-10-06 23:03:34.209 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is
/home/paul/.local/share/jupyter/lab
[I 23:03:34.214 NotebookApp] [Jupytext Server Extension] NotebookApp.contents_manager_class is (a subclass of) jupytext.TextFileContentsManager already - OK
[I 23:03:34.215 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /tmp/so
[I 23:03:34.215 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.6 is running at:
[I 23:03:34.215 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=7a1b13f2e290eb348ac24ca13da336ced7e163f7d161685d
[I 23:03:34.216 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=7a1b13f2e290eb348ac24ca13da336ced7e163f7d161685d
[I 23:03:34.216 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 23:03:34.245 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/paul/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-50013-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=7a1b13f2e290eb348ac24ca13da336ced7e163f7d161685d
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=7a1b13f2e290eb348ac24ca13da336ced7e163f7d161685d
```